# Adding a Ruby on Rails ActiveJob background task from within a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Got this working!

My rails 6 app has a background job / ActiveJob that's utilizing Sidekiq to send notifications to users. This works great. I can call SendMessageJob.perform_later(user, "title", "body") from the console, no problem.

```
/app/jobs/send_message_job.rb

class SendMessageJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default
  sidekiq_options retry: 3

  def perform(user, title, body)
    # Do something later
    user.send_message(title, body)
  end
end
```

I also have a rake task that runs every 10 minutes via Heroku's Scheduler to look up all the reminders that need to be sent out.

```
rake send_reminder_messages
```

This is the rake task.

```
/lib/tasks/scheduler.rake

task send_reminder_messages: :environment do
  t = Time.now.utc
  events = Event.where('scheduled_at >= ? AND scheduled_at <= ? and completed_at is null', t - 10.minutes, t)
  events.each do |e|
    timer = e.timer
    user = timer.user
    title = timer.name + " timer due"
    body = "Don't forget about your " + timer.name + " event."
    user.send_message(title, body)
  end
end
```

Instead of running user.send_message inside the rake task, I'd like to add this to my SendMessageJob queue from the rake task.

I got this working like so:

```
task send_reminder_messages: :environment do
  t = Time.now.utc
  events = Event.where('scheduled_at >= ? AND scheduled_at <= ? and completed_at is null', t - 10.minutes, t)
  events.each do |e|
    timer = e.timer
    user = timer.user
    title = timer.name + " timer due"
    body = "Don't forget about your " + timer.name + " event."
    SendMessageJob.perform_later(user, title, body)
  end
end
```

Comment: Assuming everything is named correctly, you shouldn't have an issue queueing from a rake task. It knows everything about your application — for example, you're hitting `Event` just fine. What's the NameError stacktrace?

Comment: @JoshBrody I tried this again after your comment and now, this works even without wrapping the worker class in a module. I must have had a typo in my method name or maybe didn't call the worker SendReminderMessages.perform_later(user, title, body).